# React shallow rendering - can't find text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I `console.log` the `wrapper.text()` I can see the text '1410'. But when I test for it:

```
 import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
 import expect from 'expect';
 import mockery from 'mockery';

import Table from '../../../src/components/elements/_common/Table';


describe('Table', () => {

beforeEach(()=> {
    mockery.enable({
        warnOnReplace: false,
        warnOnUnregistered: false,
        useCleanCache:true
    });
});

afterEach(()=> {
    mockery.disable()
});

it('should render totals', () => {
    const TableComp= require('../../../src/component.js');
    var wrapper = shallow(<TableComp sectionData={{Total: 1410}} />);
    console.log("Output ",wrapper.text());
    expect(wrapper.text()).contains('1410').toBe(true);
});
```

I get:

**typeError: 0 _expect2.default() contains not a function**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains()` method should be `toContain()`.

This is an alias of [toInclude()](https://github.com/mjackson/expect#toinclude)